# Extracting values from a semi-colon delimited string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a string from where I am trying to extract the value assigned to AccountName

```
var myString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myAccountName;AccountKey=myAccountKey;EndpointSuffix=whatever.com"
```

So my desired output is "myAccountName". Is RegEx the best way to go?

Comment: Why? if you're hard coding it just hard code the different values in variables.

Comment: Hard coding it would mean having to update another entry as that changes. Basically I am reading this string from an Azure KeyVault during runtime so it's not really hardcoded. Extracting the value from this string and injecting it into other methods is what I am seeking to do right now

Comment: You haven't shown any attempt at implementing a solution here. That makes this feel like you want us to just write some code for you. You seem to know about Regex. Did you try that? Did it work? What issues did you find with it? Did you try solving this problem in some other way? Please show your attempt and clearly explain what's not working about it.

Comment: If you're reading it from the key vault you can split it up into multiple values. It doesn't make any sense to split and parse the string values like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hum, to split out that value?

This works:

```
        var myString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myAccountName;AccountKey=myAccountKey;EndpointSuffix=whatever.com";

        string[] MyDeLim = {"AccountName="};
        string res = myString.Split(MyDeLim ,StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
        res = res.Split(';')[0];
        Debug.Print(res);
```

However, regex, it even better, say like this:

```
        // however, this looks to be even better:
        // using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

        res = Regex.Split(myString,"AccountName=")[1];
        res = Regex.Split(res, ";")[0];
```

And you could I suppose put above into one line, but regex.Split looks to be about the best.

So, we basic chop the string in "two parts" based on AccountName=

Then grab 2nd array value, and chop on ";", and we get our result.